# gcloud: is it possible to change the default project based on the current folder?

Tags: bash, config, gcloud, direnv

I'm working on several gcloud projects and I'm tired of having to type out `--project XYZ` every time I need to call a command, or worse having the command execute on the wrong project if I forget to add that in.

Comment: Recommend you also `gcloud config unset project` to avoid "having the command execute on the wrong project".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, by using gcloud [configurations](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/configurations) together with [direnv](https://direnv.net).

Create a configuration (this will also activate it):

- `gcloud config configurations create <cool_new_config>`
- `gcloud config set project <project>`

Install `direnv`. Hook it into your shell. With bash I used `~/.bash_profile` instead of directed `~/.bashrc`.

Navigate to the project folder where you want the switch to occur.

- create a file named .envrc
- add line `export CLOUDSDK_ACTIVE_CONFIG_NAME=<cool_new_config>`
- whitelist file with `direnv allow`

Verify functionality:

- open a new terminal window
- active the default/prior configuration
- navigate to folder
- confirm with `gcloud config configurations list`

Optional: rebuild the rest of the configuration

- view all configurations: `gcloud config configurations list`
- describe old configuration `gcloud config configurations describe <default>`
- login: `gcloud auth login`
- set region: `gcloud config set compute/region <us-central1>`
- set zone: `gcloud config set compute/zone <us-central1-a>`
- etc.